# Java - Return type of generic type

Tags: java, generics

Im new ish to Generics in Java but how can a return type be compiled at runtime, is this possible? 
I have a class that acts as a decorator over an entity, if the entity property is "mapped", then a different value is returned, however the value from the property of the entity can be any type.

My code is as follows: Obviously GENERIC_TYPE is the type i want to know or can be a wildcard

```
package com.example;

public final class ObjectPropertyGetter
{
    private final Map mappings;

    public ObjectPropertyGetter(Map<String, GENERIC_TYPE> mappings)
    {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    public GENERIC_TYPE getValueFor(Object entity, String property)
    {
        GENERIC_TYPE valueOfProperty = getValueOfProperty(property); // left out for simplicity

        if (mappings.containsKey(property)) {
            return mappings.get(property);
        }

        return valueOfProperty;
    }

    public class MyEntity{
        public String foo;
        public Integer bar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, GENERIC_TYPE> mappings = new HashMap();
        mappings.put("bar", 3);

        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        entity.foo = "a";
        entity.bar = 2;

        ObjectPropertyGetter propGetter = new ObjectPropertyGetter(mappings);

        String foo = propGetter.getValueFor(entity, "foo"); // equals "a"
        Integer bar = propGetter.getValueFor(entity, "bar"); // equal 3
    }
}
```

Comment: A return type (or any Java type) is a compile time thing. I'd say use `Object` where you have `GENERIC_TYPE` and cast the return type to what you need. You could hide the cast with a generic cast, but that isn't any safer, and manually casting shows explicitly that a cast is happening.

Comment: You should also read about [raw types, and why you shouldn't use them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

Comment: Yes, what do you have in mappings? Class or POJO?

Comment: I've just realised tha StackOverflow was changing the code i'd written,i had < but it stripped them out, must of thought they were html tags

Comment: @ControlAltDel The actual amount of "some" understanding is subjective, and the comment you posted provides no productive criticism. In my honest opinion, he is at least trying and is showing he knows something to do with Generics. Keep your comments to yourself :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel this is not a constructive comment, show OP the error or at least link some source to clarify...

Answer (score 1):

Another design, besides generic, would be a wrapper around `MyEntity` that sometimes delegates, and sometimes does something else.

First you need to declare an `Entity` interface, that `MyEntity` implements:

```
interface Entity {
    String getFoo();
    int getBar();
}

class MyEntity implements Entity {...}
```

Then you can create decorators using anonymous classes:

```
public static Entity mapBar(Entity toWrap, int newBar) {
    return new Entity() {
        @Override
        public String getFoo() {
            return toWrap.getFoo(); // delegate
        }

        @Override
        public int getBar() {
            return newBar; // return another value
        }
    };
}
```

Then use it like:

```
Entity ent = new MyEntity();
ent = mapBar(ent, 3);

String foo = ent.getFoo(); // "a"
int bar = ent.getBar(); // 3
```

Comment: yes i did think about this, but i want this "component" to be used elsewhere as I have quite a few entities i will want to do this for, not just the one, otherwise it would be the solution

Comment: @Matt well, you don't _have_ to overwrite the original `Entity`, you could keep both.

Comment: true, also i have approx 10 fields i might need to override, they need to be easy to configure. I didnt mention this initially as it was too much too soon :)

Comment: @Matt This is where my opinion differs. Yes, writing a method for every field seems like _more_ work, but it really is a part of the type `Entity` and will be more expressive than using a map. i.e. the extra work (which is not really that much imho) is worth it.